# OnRoomListUpdate from inside a room (PUN 2)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon, real-time-multiplayer

**Short question:** how can I get the list of existing rooms while staying in a room?

**Long explanation:**

I am developing a game for a client and I have a problem.

In short in the game I can see all the existing rooms from the menu and I can enter one of them (to view the existing rooms I join a lobby and use OnRoomListUpdate ()). Entering the room I would like to see the existing rooms again to change room, but I cannot enter a room and stay in the lobby at the same time, and therefore I cannot get the list of available rooms with OnRoomListUpdate ().

I have been working with Unity and PUN for years, but I can't find an elegant solution to this problem.

I use PUN 2 and Unity 2021 LTS.

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Once joining a room within PUN, you get moved from the Master Server (which has the list of all rooms), to a Game Server. There isn't a way to receive room list updates while inside a room because the Game Server simply doesn't have a list of rooms.

If you try doing a custom room query, like `PhotonNetwork.GetCustomRoomList(TypedLobby.Default, "1=1");`, it will throw an exception saying it's not allowed on the current server.

Theoretically, it's possible to keep an external list of rooms using [Photon Server Webhooks](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/web-extensions/webhooks) with PathCreate, PathClose, and PathGameProperties, though it might be more trouble than it's worth. (plus, you need your own external server)